# Getting node ancestors using Doctrine 1.2 and Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, nodes, doctrine-1.2, nested-sets

I've a little trouble while trying to get all ancestors from a node;

This is my schema.yml:

```
Constante:
connection: doctrine
tableName: constante
actAs:
NestedSet:
  hasManyRoots: true
  rootColumnName: parent_id
columns:
id:
  type: integer(8)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: true
  autoincrement: true
parent_id:
  type: integer(8)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
lft:
  type: integer(8)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
rgt:
  type: integer(8)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
level:
  type: integer(8)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
cod_interno:
  type: string(5)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: false
  autoincrement: false
nombre:
  type: string(64)
  fixed: false
  unsigned: false
  primary: false
  notnull: true
  autoincrement: false
```

And this is how I'm trying to get all ancestors from a node (which is not a root)

```
$path        = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Constante')->find($condicion); // $condicion = 57
$node        = $path->getNode();
$isLeaf      = $node->isLeaf(); //var_dump throws true
$ancestors   = $node->getAncestors(); //var_dump throws false
$isValidNode = $node->isValidNode(); //var_dump throws true
```

As `$ancestors == false` I cannot iterate over it and get all ancestors (I'm trying to build a simple breadcrumb)

This is what I have stored in DB, this is real data (for testing puporse only)

```
+---------++---------++---------++---------++----------++---------+
|ID       ||PARENT_ID||LFT      ||RGT      ||LEVEL     ||NOMBRE   |
|---------||---------||---------||---------||----------||---------|
|56       ||56       ||1        ||4        ||0         ||COUNTRY  | --> this is root
|57       ||56       ||2        ||3        ||1         ||CANADA   | --> child of root
+---------++---------++---------++---------++----------++---------+
```

[According to this](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Node/Doctrine_Node_NestedSet.class.html#det_methods_getAncestors) if Ancestors returns false, it means that the selected node is a root.

I've spent hours looking for a solution with no luck.

If you need further information, don't hesitate to ask for it!

**EDIT:** I've made a mistake when typing what is in the table, thanks to olivierw by alert me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share my solution, hopefully it will be useful for somebody else:

Action:

```
//action.class.php
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {

$condicion = $request->getParameter('id') ? $request->getParameter('id') : 0;

if ($condicion > 0) {
  $path = $tree = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Constante')->find($condicion);
} else {
  $tree = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Constante');
  $path = null;
}

$this->constantes = $tree;
$this->path = $path;
$this->setTemplate('index');

}
```

View:

```
//indexSuccess.php
<?php
$var = (is_null($sf_request->getParameter('id'))) ? $constantes->getTree()->fetchRoots() : $constantes->getNode()->getChildren();
?>

<?php if ($var): foreach ($var as $constante): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $constante->getNombre() ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
  endforeach;
endif;
?>
```

Partial:

```
//_breadcrumb.php
<?php

if ($path) {

  echo '<ul class="breadcrumb">';

  $node = $path->getNode();
  $ancestors = $node->getAncestors();

  if ($ancestors)
    foreach ($ancestors AS $ancestor) {
      echo '<li>' . link_to($ancestor->getNombre(), 'constantes/more?id=' . $ancestor->getId()) . '<span class="divider">/</span></li>';
    }

  echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

I think that the code is self-explanatory, but if you have any question, please let me know!

Comment: Great! but I don't understand why `$node->getAncestors()` is working now and don't return `false` as in your question.

Comment: Hi! I rewrote this function from scratch, I think that the problem in the previous function was a setBaseQuery with an incorrect statement. I think that this one is way elegant, best

Comment: `setBaseQuery` ? Ho sure! this is way elegant!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error in the `rgt` field in your table. If `id 56` is the root, it should have `rgt = 4` and `id 57` should have `rgt = 3`. So your table should read:

```
+---------++---------++---------++---------++----------++---------+
|ID       ||PARENT_ID||LFT      ||RGT      ||LEVEL     ||NOMBRE   |
|---------||---------||---------||---------||----------||---------|
|56       ||56       ||1        ||4        ||0         ||COUNTRY  |
|57       ||56       ||2        ||3        ||1         ||CANADA   |
+---------++---------++---------++---------++----------++---------+
```

So you will get the ancestors correctly.

Comment: Hi, I've posted my solution, please check it out! thanks a lot